# How do I add an image to the default layout in Typo3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I want to add the company logo to the default layout page in Typo3 (located in `myextension/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/Default.html`).

However, using the relative path as a source in an img-tag does not seem to work (I used `../../../Public/Images/imagename.jpg`). The console shows that Typo3 seems to be looking in the following location: `http://localhost/Public/Images/addressicon.jpg`.

How do I insert the image located at `myextension/Resources/Public/Images/imagename.jpg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `/typo3conf/ext/myextension/Resources/Public/Images/imagename.jpg`

I think `EXT:myextension/Resources/Public/Images/imagename.jpg` should work too.

Comment: Thank you! It works without the slash so: typo3conf/ext/myextension/Resources/Public/Images/imagename.jpg

Comment: I would recommend it with the slash to be cure that it starts from the root. because otherwise it would take the base path from the current url. If you didn't have a <base> tag setted

Comment: might depend on the specific usage: if it is used immediate in an `img` tag the slash is good, but if used for an image generation like an `image` VH the slash would indicate an absolute path on the server which is incorrect.